# Using a .catch instead of try/catch block

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling

Instead of using a traditional `try/catch` to handle errors when sending requests like below

```js
let body;
try {
    const response = await sendRequest(
        "POST",
        "/api/AccountApi/RefundGetStatus",
        JSON.stringify(refundParams),
        undefined,
        headers
    );
    body = response.body;
} catch (error) {
    log("error", "An error occurred sending a request", { error });
    throw createError("An error has occurred", DefaultErrors.API_ERROR);
}
```

I was thinking if it's possible to achieve the same result rewriting the error handling like below.

```js
const response = await sendRequest(
    "POST",
    "/api/AccountApi/RefundGetStatus",
    JSON.stringify(refundParams),
    undefined,
    headers
).catch((err: any) => {
    log("error", "An error occurred sending a request", { err });
    throw createError("An error has occurred", DefaultErrors.API_ERROR);
});
```

Would the above code block be able to handle undefined errors and perhaps `JSON.parse` errors ?

Comment: No, thats not how error catching works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both

```
try { 
  await sendRequest()
} catch (err) {
  // do something
}
```

or

```
sendRequest().catch(err => { // do something})
```

to catch an error.

Below is a simple example, you can paste it to [typescript playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmYAmAleBHArvaMC8MAFNAE4BccUJAlmAOYCU+AfDAN4BQM3MJ8UmEmBhh4AdxgAFEiAC21BIUJ8IIADYA3eABpe8AFbxgUJnlaceluPwAq1WfBCYoS0+a5XPoSOvgA6NRA6QgByOn49CAAHcAQQhgBuD09LPkNjUPgSGRIYBwgIAENw+KSUmABfXQAmAAZ6hmTKxoqODm9cKBxYAkKIAE8wYCIGM3YmwrFC6lgEZDQsbtCkQqhC+L9gVeAAC0Is3LGLFI7fAKDM7Lxr6+YQ3QPGywqWtq7oQkSOIA) to give it a try.

```
const sendRequest = (str: string) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('get response');
      reject('error message');
    }, 2000)
  })
}

const test1 = async ()=> {
  try{
    await sendRequest('data');
  } catch (err) {
    // will print 'err===> error message'
    console.log('err===>', err)
  }
}

const test2 = async ()=> {
  sendRequest('data').catch(err => {
    // will print 'err===> error message'
    console.log('err=====>', err)
  })
}

test1();
test2();
```

test1() and test2() will both catch the error.